# Calculating the duration (seconds) between two DateTime columns in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime

I have two respective DateTime columns (E & G) in excel, and have inserted in column F a space for the duration between these two columns to be calculated.

I have formatted both of these columns to be Custom *(dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss)* formats which suits the dataset I am working with.

```
   |           E          |           F         |           G          |
===+======================+=====================+======================+
1  | 22/01/2024  23:46:20 |        #VALUE!      | 23/01/2024  00:01:26 |
```

When I've tried the following formula to calculate the duration between the two, I am met with a #VALUE! error:

```
=(G1-E1)
```

I was anticipating to then have to convert my answer into seconds had I been able to even get a result from that formula, but I cannot escape the Value Error. Any suggestions for why this might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be working with text-that-looks-like-a-datetime.

Comment: That worked to me, I got 15:06. I multiplied that by 86400 and I got the result in seconds. You must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `'DATEVALUE'` and `'TIMEVALUE'` functions to convert text values to date and time values

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(G1, FIND(" ", G1)+1, LEN(G1))) - TIMEVALUE(MID(E1, FIND(" ", E1)+1, LEN(E1)))
```

this formula extracts time  from the date-time values in columns E and G and calculates time difference